# Embedding theorem for finite p-groups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

One knows that any countable group can be embedded in a 2-generated group. Also, any finite group is a subgroup of a 2-generated finite group, namely by the Cayley embedding. Does the same hold if we restrict to finite $p$-groups, where $p$ is some prime, i.e. is any finite $p$-group a subgroup of a 2-generated finite $p$-group?

Note that the minimal number of generators of the Sylow subgroup of the symmetric groups grow with their order. Thus the Cayley embedding would not suffice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is proved in

> Neumann, B. H. and Neumann, H. (1959), Embedding Theorems for Groups. Journal of the London Mathematical Society, s1-34: 465–479. doi:10.1112/jlms/s1-34.4.465

At least, it says in the introduction that they prove this. For some reason I don't seem to be able to access the full article online at the moment.